# openssl_csr_sign always return false

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate

I use the following script to generate a new signed certificate:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Generate a new private (and public) key pair
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new();

// Generate a certificate signing request

$dn = array(
    "countryName" => "US",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "Atlantis",
    "localityName" => "NeverEverLand",
    "organizationName" => "only me",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "blah",
    "commonName" => "bleh",
    "emailAddress" => "test@test.com"
);

$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);


$cacert = file_get_contents('ca.crt');
echo $cacert . "<BR/>";
echo "<BR/>";
$ca_key = file_get_contents('ca.key');
$cakey = array($ca_key, "mysecretpass");
echo $ca_key . "<BR/>";
echo "<BR/>";

$sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, $cacert, $cakey, 365);

var_dump($sscert);
echo "<BR/>";
echo "<BR/>";


openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $pkeyout, "mypassword"); var_dump($pkeyout);
echo "<BR/>";
echo "<BR/>";

openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrout); var_dump($csrout);
echo "<BR/>";
echo "<BR/>";
openssl_x509_export($sscert, $certout); var_dump($certout);
echo "<BR/>";
echo "<BR/>";

while (($e = openssl_error_string()) !== false) {
    echo $e . "\n";
}
?>
```

As you can see in the output it can read ca.crt and ca.key. The pass is also correct (changed in above source).

This is the output of the script:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFGDCCAwACCQCO584jngEQdjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBOMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV ... XZ8YaIOkiV4pEiR5 -----END CERTIFICATE----- 

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,E616BBF003C1FA9D ... VCPNIOlGzmKUvDn0iMKE0KRmN8o3ip8oy4HKPZmuh4h+qznZdNF/pBTurqcNVN/P -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 

bool(false) 

string(1834) "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- MIIFDjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIBX0RFXQVx+ICAggA Bfw= -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- " 

string(1045) "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- MIICzDCCAbQCAQAwgYYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIDAhBdGxhbnRpczEW zZL71nx/8MgG8hyg63vRRJewb/cCIt1q9A4SwGB9iDe75CbR3ij3jHMftXUfvYhV -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- " 

NULL
```

so the command

```
openssl_csr_sign($csr, $cacert, $cakey, 365);
```

returns FALSE, even if all input parameters are valid.

Using CentOS 6.4 / Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) / mod_ssl/2.2.15

Comment: I had similar problem, and for me it turned out that the openssl config file in use requested some additional dn field. Check your config, may be there is some unexpected setting.